# VB.NET change SQL query in TableAdapter?

Tags: vb.net, dataset, tableadapter

I am loking for how change a SQL query in TableAdapter. 
In the old VB was DataEnvironmement where was simply

```
Set rs = DataEnvironment1.rsQuery
  DataEnvironment1.Commands.Item("Query").CommandText = "SELECT row FROM table"
  DataEnvironment1.Query
set rs = Nothing
```

How i Do it in vb.net ?

Something like this:

```
Dim rs As New Databaze2.DataSet1TableAdapters.Query
TableAdapterrs.Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT row FROM table"
```

But this is not working.

I ask for this because i looking for some way how insert a liitle complicated query. Problem probably is in combined included select and two parameters and only one column DATUM_CAS. 
Because:

1. without this 2 parameters ? the command is OK
2. without included selects the command is OK
3. when I substitute ? by correct date_time the command is OK

[see the screenshot with command and eror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQdk5.png)

Comment: I have no idea what that error message is saying.  I don't use MySQL much at all but my first guess would be that it doesn't support the use of a question mark as a parameter place-holder.  I know that Microsoft databases do but I have no idea whether MySQL does.

Answer (score 0):

You don't do it in code.  A table adapter is a type and the SQL code of each query is part of that type.  Pretty much any modifications get done in the designer.  You can open your `DataSet` in the designer by double-clicking it in the Solution Explorer.  You can then select a table adapter and configure it in the Properties window.

You can modify the SQL code of the default query there if you want but, generally speaking, you should not.  You can add extra queries to the same table adapter if you need something different.  For instance, the default query will generally retrieve all columns of all rows and you execute it via the `Fill` method.  You can add an extra query that has a `WHERE` clause to filter the rows returned and that would be executed via a different method that you name.  For instance, if you want to filter by a `DateOfBirth` column then you'd name the method `FillByDateOfBirth`.

You'd only edit the default query if you wanted to change the columns in the result set, which must also change the schema of the associated `DataTable`.